# Create new column in query from rows of data using SQL self joining aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, self-join

I have 3 different (people and address info) that currently are in 3 rows. I need them to all be in one row per project number. I am thinking I need to do self joins but am getting stuck on syntax. This needs to be a query that isn't aggregated and can not use the pivot function.

Current SQL Statement:

```
Select ActivityID, NAMETYPE, NAME, ADDRESS1, CITY, Zip from People
```

Current output

```
ActivityID      NAMETYPE     NAME                        ADDRESS                    CITY    STATE ZIP
SPAR19-00001    APPLICANT    weler, Inc.                  W204 Goldendale Road      town    MI  12354
SPAR19-00001    OWNER        Aircraft Services LLC        26 Aviation Dr         villiage   MI  12345
SPAR19-00001    ARCHITECT    Engineering Consultatns      700 Parkway               Grove   MI  12345
```

Want it to look like

```
ActivityID   APPLNAME      APPLADDRESS       APPLCITY    OWNERNAME        OWNERADDRESS    OWNERCITY etc
SPAR19-00001 weler, Inc.   W204 Goldendale Road  town    Aircraft Services 26 Aviation Dr villiage
```

Here is a picture for better clarity.
[image]

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? also, could you format your current and expected output clearly. Its hard to follow that.

Comment: sql server and I see that is is hard to read. I will include pictures. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you would want to group by the column and use max(case logic) as follows

```
select ActivityID
       , max(case when NAMETYPE='APPLICANT' then NAME end) as applname
       , max(case when NAMETYPE='APPLICANT' then ADDRESS1 end) as appladdress
       , max(case when NAMETYPE='APPLICANT' then CITY end) as applcity
       , max(case when NAMETYPE='OWNER' then NAME end) as ownername
       , max(case when NAMETYPE='OWNER' then ADDRESS1 end) as owneraddress
       , max(case when NAMETYPE='OWNER' then CITY end) as ownercity
  from People
group by ActivityID
```